# Unable to open the app when disable the Open button after APK installation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-install-apk

I am disabling 'Open' button which comes up after APK installation. But my app does not open after it. It gives me error 'Sorry not able to open the application' after I try to open it. I tried all the possible solution but nothing works.

Thanks in advance.

**Manifest** as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.activity"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">   

<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="14"
   android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

 <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>  
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">  
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>  
       <intent-filter>  
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">  
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">  
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE">  
               <data android:scheme="callback" android:host="com.example.activity"/>  
               </category>  
           </category>
           </action>
       </intent-filter>
       </action>
    </intent-filter>

   </activity>

 </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have made a mistake in your intent-filters. Try to replace your `<activity>` element with this one:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name">    
   <intent-filter>  
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">  
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>  
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">  
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE">
       <data android:scheme="callback" android:host="com.example.activityname"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```